# Symfony2 Compressing CSS without uglifyCSS and possibly using Sass :compressed

Tags: symfony, sass, compass-sass

I'm using assetic within Symfony2 to load all of my assets, and I'm also using the compass filter. All my code is now out of development so I need to compress it if possible. I've looked into the uglifyCSS filters but I don't and probably can't install Node on my server.

Is there a way to make Symfony2 use the Sass --style :compressed functionality so my code is minified when i generate assets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some time ago I had the same problem. It is quite easy to overcome, but there is nothing mentioned in the documentation. This is how you do it:

```
// in config.yml
assetic:
    filters:
        scss:
            style: compressed
```

This will pass `--style` argument to `sass` with the value `compressed`.

Answer (score 2):

In you production configuration file you can set :

```
assetic:
    filters:
        compass:
            # ...
            style: compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

I use compass to generate the css files directly (using the compass watch command) and have those dumped to the public folder.  In compass, you can change the output_style to one of these 4 - :expanded, :nested, :compact or :compressed.  Using compressed is the one you would want.